# How to initialize unmanaged static pointer in C++/CLI code?

Tags: .net, static, c++-cli

I'm not able to initialize a static native pointer inside a managed class.

Here's the detail: I created a C++/CLI console project and declared a static unmanaged pointer inside. However I can't initialize the static pointer with any means (but if I put the pointer into an anonymous namespace, there's no problem, demoed in the code). Did u meet similar situations and got solutions for it?

Code here:

```
class MyTask
{
public:
    int m_index;
    MyTask()
    {
        m_index = 0;
    }
};

namespace
{
    static MyTask* s_pTask;
}

public ref class MyApplication
{
public:
    static MyTask* sm_pTask;

    static void InitizlizeStaticMembers(MyTask* pTask)
    {
        sm_pTask = pTask;
    }

    void AddTask()
    {
        sm_pTask = new MyTask();
    }
};

void main()
{
    MyApplication^ app = gcnew MyApplication();

    // 1st, doesn't work (sm_pTask is still null after the execution)
    MyApplication::sm_pTask = new MyTask();
    // 2nd, doesn't work (pTask can be initialized correctly, sm_pTask is still null after the execution)
    MyTask* pTask = new MyTask();
    MyApplication::InitizlizeStaticMembers(pTask);
    // 3rd, doesn't work (sm_pTask is still null after the execution)
    app->AddTask();
    // 4th, work(s_pTask can be initialized correctly)
    s_pTask = new MyTask();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that (with VS2005) the debugger confirms what you said - the value of the pointer doesn't change as it gets updated.  But the code is actually working if you make it output something.

I believe this is a bug in the debugger.

Comment: VS2008 seems to have the same problem, but it seems to be corrected in VS2010 Beta.
I confirm that when you print the value whether with std::cout native method or System::Console::WriteLine() managed method, this code appears to behave correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with the code and it works fine for me. The anonymous namespace is not needed.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

class MyTask
{
public:
    int m_index;
    MyTask()
    {
        m_index = 0;
    }
};

static MyTask* s_pTask;

public ref class MyApplication
{
public:
    static MyTask* sm_pTask = NULL;

    static void InitizlizeStaticMembers(MyTask* pTask)
    {
        sm_pTask = pTask;
    }

    void AddTask()
    {
        sm_pTask = new MyTask();
    }
};

void main()
{
    MyApplication^ app = gcnew MyApplication();

    // 1st, doesn't work (sm_pTask is still null after the execution)
    std::cout << "MyApplication::sm_pTask before new " << MyApplication::sm_pTask << '\n'; // 0
    MyApplication::sm_pTask = new MyTask();
    std::cout << "MyApplication::sm_pTask after new " << MyApplication::sm_pTask << '\n'; // 003B8170

    MyTask* pTask = new MyTask();
    std::cout << "pTask= " << pTask << '\n'; // 003B81A0
    MyApplication::InitizlizeStaticMembers(pTask);
    std::cout << "MyApplication::sm_pTask = " << MyApplication::sm_pTask << '\n'; // 003B81A0

    app->AddTask();    
    s_pTask = new MyTask();
}
```